# How to stop angular from scrolling to the top

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular-powered table on my page, with sorting. When I click a column to change the sorting, it makes a $http request for the new data and reapplies it. All works well, but it annoyingly scrolls the page to the top.

My sort links are rendered by a directive: `<a ng-click='sort()' href='#' ng-transclude></a>`

My sort handler is defined in the directive too:

```
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
    scope.sort = function () {
        // Want to check the pagerInfo of the controller
        scope.$parent.onsort(scope.sortby, sortDir);
        return false;
    };
}
```

This just calls through to a function on the contoller to refetch the data.

I've tried:

1. Returning false from the sort function
2. Adding this to my module to disable angular's scrolling: `var ngGrid = angular.module("ngGrid", []).value('$anchorScroll', angular.noop);`
3. Setting a `min-height` in css on the table in case that was causing it
4. Using `ng-href` instead of href in the anchor link.

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

In my sort function, instead of returning false, I needed to `event.preventDefault();`

Full function:

```
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.sort = function () {
            // Want to check the pagerInfo of the controller
            var sortDir = "desc";
            if (scope.$parent.pagerInfo.sortby == scope.sortby) {
                sortDir = scope.$parent.pagerInfo.sortdir == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
            }
            scope.$parent.onsort(scope.sortby, sortDir);
            event.preventDefault();
        };
    }
```

Comment: where is the event coming from? this is give an error